# Weird Livewire + Turbolinks behavior

Tags: laravel, turbolinks, laravel-livewire

I'm building an admin panel in TALL (Laravel 7) + Turbolinks. One section only includes a Livewire component that shows a paginated table of `Product` elements and a search field (the only "strange" thing that I'm doing before this is injecting a `Market` model instance to the request in a middleware).

The problem arises when I go to /products route where is the livewire component included nothing works... The records of the first page are *fine*, but pagination links are dead and search field does nothing, no console errors, no livewire errors, it's like javascript is not working at all, and here's the strangest thing: if I reload the page, **the `Market` data I loaded in middleware is added to the query string and everything starts working as intended**.

Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $market = Market::findOrFail(session('selected_market'));
    $request->request->add(['market' => $market]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Livewire Component:

```
class ProductsTable extends Component{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search = '';
    protected $queryString = [
        'search' => ['except' => ''],
        'page' => ['except' => 1],
    ];

    public function render(){
        $products = Product::where('market_id', request('market')->id)
        ->when($this->search !== '', function($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$this->search}%");
            $query->orWhere('brand', 'like', "%{$this->search}%");
        })->paginate(15);

        return view('livewire.products-table', ['products' => $products]);
    }
}
```

Livewire Component View:

```
<input wire:model.debounce.500ms="search" type="search" name="search" id="search">

<table>
    @forelse($products as $product)
        <tr onclick="Turbolinks.visit('{{ route('product', $product->id) }}')">
            <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    @empty
        <tr><td>Nothing to show for {{ $search }}</td></tr>
    @endforelse
</table>

{{ $products->links() }}
```

I'm really confused and tired with this, I have no clue what is going on and similar questions haven't been answered clearly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was as simple as adding this to your scripts:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(event) {
  window.livewire.restart();
});
```